# possible to overload the << operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to overload the << operator as follows:

```
class A
    attr_accessor :secret_array

...
# assume the array gets initialized at some point
...

    def public_array
        # when it's an rvalue, load it from cache
        load_array_from_cache
    end

    def public_array << (what)
        # but when it's an lvalue, send it to the secret array
        secret_array << what
    end

end
```

My code does not work obviously, but is this possible and if so, what's the syntax?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: `def <<(value) some_logic end` should do the trick. [Post on the topic](http://nicholasjohnson.com/ruby/ruby-course/exercises/operator-overloading/)

Comment: What's the point to have an `attr_accessor` for `secret_array` if it's secret? With that code you make this array accessible from outside for reading and writing

Comment: JFYI, in ruby we don't operate in terms of lvalue/rvalue. Instead we use "value", "receiver" and "message"

Comment: Additional FYI ruby does not allow "overloading". One can override a method but you cannot overload it (meaning same name different signature) in this case the second definition is the only definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A
  def initialize
    @secret_array = []
  end

  def public_array
    @secret_array
  end

  def <<(what)
    @secret_array << what
    self
  end
end

a = A.new
# => #<A:0x000055e10943df60 @secret_array=[]> 
a << 'q' << 'w' << 'r'
# => #<A:0x000055e10943df60 @secret_array=["q", "w", "r"]> 
a.public_array
# => ["q", "w", "r"]
```

Comment: This getter gives callers full control over the "secret" array, btw :) (except maybe nullifying it)

Comment: Correct, it's safer to use `dup`. I'm just not sure about OP's intentions

Comment: I _think_ what he wanted to do is `a.public_array << 'whatever'`, which works out of the box, without needing to override anything.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev don't we always have full control though? Ruby doesn't really safeguard what control means e.g. `instance_variable_set`, all the `eval` methods, etc.

Comment: @engineersmnky: hard to hide something from a determined caller, sure. But here it's trivial to shoot oneself in the foot _accidentally_.